# LaTeX - Let table be page wide in the IEEE template

Tags: tables, templates, multicolumn

I'm currently using the IEEE template, as it allows for the use of floats within a two column document. I am trying to make a table the width of the page (spanning both columns) at either the top or the bottom of the page. The code that I am using works fine in a normal document, but it fails in the IEEE template. Is there anyone who knows how to place a page wide table in this?

```
\begin{table}[b]
\caption{A summary of the EMG sensor, marker cluster and probe position locations}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccccc}
% The contents of the table are not that interesting
\toprule
{EMG Sensors} & {Marker Clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Probe points} \\
    \midrule
    Biceps femoris (L/R) & Foot (L/R) & Shoe tip (L/R) & Calcaneus (L/R) & Troch. major (L/R)\\
    Rectus femoris (L/R) & Lower leg (L/R)  & Calcaneus shoe (L/R) & Maleolus lat. (L/R) & SIAS (L/R)\\
    Adductor longus (L/R) & Upper leg (L/R) & CM1 shoe (L/R) & Maleolus med. (L/R) & SIPS (L/R)\\
    Gastrocnemius medialis (L/R) & Pelvis & CM5 shoe (L/R) & Caput fibula (L/R) & Xiphoid proc.\\
    Tibialis anterior (L/R) & Trunk & CM1 (L/R) & Epicondylus lat. (L/R) & Jugular notch\\
    Gluteus medius (L/R) & Head & CM5 (L/R) & Epicondylus med. (L/R) & C7\\
      &  & Occiput & Head vertex & Sellion \\
    \bottomrule
% but I included it to be complete as complete as possible
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

The weird thing is that it does try to put it at the bottom of the page, but it's overlapping with the text that's already there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think the same applies here as most other two column documents, i.e. use `table*`. See [In a 2-columned document, how do you get a table to stretch across the entire width?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64912)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok, I already tried that, at first I thought it just disappeared, it did not. However, it places the table at the bottom of the next page. Is there a way to get it on the bottom of the page that you're currently on? I also still get errors: `Undefined control sequence`

EDIT: Ok..... So I did what any beginner would do and thought to myself "Well, maybe if I just place the code a page up the table will also move up a page".... Yeah... That worked... Thanks alot nonetheless! I'm always amazed by how helpful you all are!

Comment: By default such floats can only be placed at the top of the page, not the bottom. You can put them on the bottom by loading the `dblfloatfix` package and using the `[b]` specifier, but not the bottom of the current page. See http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=2colfloat As for the error, it is impossible to say as you didn't provide the entire error message, and we can't compile the code snippet you provided. It would be more helpful with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry for being so incomplete, I'm actually using that package. It does work now though! Thanks for the help. The error is also gone now. Would you like to write a short answer so we can close this question?

Comment: If you agree, we can rather close as a duplicate of [Placing a figure in the bottom of a page spanning the two columns of an IEEE document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235647)

Comment: Did you try the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle)? You can take a look at the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248976/how-to-add-full-page-table-in-two-column-style/249000#249000)  to a similar question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's fine, I don't have the reputation to do so though (3000+)